# $pull not removing element from collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a like/unlike system. and for unlike i need to remove the user from array of likes. but the mongodb `$pull` doesn't work.
the `$inc` command works fine but `$pull` doesn't.

here is my schema

```
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User"
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    ],
    likeCount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    commentBody: {
        type: String
    },
    contentId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath: "contentType",
        required: true
    },
    contentType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ["Video", "Comment"]
    },
    isApproved: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ],
    postedOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
```

mongodb query

```
await Video.updateOne(
                { _id: contentId, likeCount: { $gt: 0 } },
                {
                    $pull: {
                        likes: decoded.id
                    },
                    $inc: { likeCount: -1 }
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your query to look like this:

```
await Video.updateOne(
                { _id: contentId, likeCount: { $gt: 0 } },
                {
                    $pull: {
                        "likes": { "_id": ObjectId(decoded.id)}
                    },
                    $inc: { likeCount: -1 }
                }
            );
```

I assume that in `devede.id` you have string, and string is not the same as `ObjectId`. Because of that we need to transform it to `ObjectId`.